# Ubuntu 14.04 software updater messed up everything

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

I was downloading software updates through software updater but by mistake closed the program.
Then I checked it was still running but was stuck at same update.
I tried to kill it but was prompted by the error that dkpg is locked by another process.
I tried restarting the machine to free it but then Ubuntu has gone in some low graphics with disabled internet and I am unable to use my mouse as well.

Edit: As I have developed the fact that none of the USB port and neither Ethernet port is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can resume your broken update progress by launching this command in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Once done, restart your computer.

Comment: Did that but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you give the output of above command?

Comment: The program which was being updated was android studio and some image files. Android studio was incompletely downloaded so running the command first gave an error of missing files and running it again gave a successful run. Cannot give the output as it is done and restarted.

Comment: You mean the command worked and solved your issue?

Comment: Nope it didn't. It just ran successfully second time gave an error of some missing files first time but the issue remains the same.

Comment: OK. You still have low graphic? Any other symptoms?

Comment: Low graphics . unable to connect to internet through Ethernet and mouse not detected

Comment: If your computer cannot connect to internet, it's strange as you could successfully run the `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: It installed the downloaded scripts that's it nothing more than that which were downloaded before restarting for the first time.

Comment: Can you give the output of `ifconfig -a`? Can you ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Ping 8.8.8.8 returned network is unreachable

Comment: The hardware ports like USB ports or Ethernet port are not working.

Comment: You may need to reinstall your Ubuntu (keep current data) using Ubuntu Live CD.